# Unable to connect to AWS EC2 Database using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I am new to python, and I am trying to connect to my AWS EC2 RDS databse but the it does not connect to the AWS db. It throws an error

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Whereas when I try to connect to my local host it connects nicely, and it says connected to Mysql database. I am using the following codes to connect to the db.

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(host='xx.xxx.xx.xxx', database='bm_new', user='dbusername', password='dbpassword')
if db.is_connected():
    print('connected to Mysql database')
```

I modified my mysql.cnf, changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and even changed it to my server IP, but the problem remains. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See if your Security Groups or NACL allow RDS traffic.

Comment: I tried to connect to it using php file, and it works and it gets connected to it but using python I cannot connect it.